# activating layers in google maps programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps

From my app, I currently invoke google map using this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:" + "45.420833" + "," + "-75.69?z=13");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I need to turn on the traffic layer upon launching the intent.

I couldn't find any simple way to do so online. I couldn't find an extra parameter to do so either :(

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Altough I have not tried it yet, this might work for you if you are using a mapView within the app:

```
mapView.setTraffic(true);
```

Comment: Not using mapview, as you see here. calling the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to turn on the traffic layer upon launching the intent.

You will have to embed `MapView` for that, AFAIK.

Comment: Again, I need to do this without embedding mapview.

Comment: @Richard Lalancette: And, again, that is not supported.

Comment: Hoping some else can come up with something. Thanks CommonsWare!